# Create GCloud VM instance with no VPC

Tags: virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, google-vpc

I need to create a Google Compute Engine Virtual Machine instance with no VPC.

For the App environment that I am using, I need to use the Public IP Address directly such as DigitalOcean Droplet, so if I run `ifconfig` command should show the interface with the public IP Address.

Answer (score 3):

Each Compute Engine instance belongs to at least one VPC network. The use case you are describing is likely impossible given **GCP**'s software-defined network architecture.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a VM in GCP without it belonging to some VPC. Console gui won't allow you that - you just have to have at least one interface.

But - there's a workaround;

- ssh to your VM and create additional user & password; add this user to `sudo` group: (`adduser username; echo 'sudouser:userspass' | chpasswd; usermod -aG google-sudoers sudouser`)
- logout
- [enable serial-console interactive aceess](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#enable_instance_access)
- login using serial console
- disable all network interfaces

This way you will have a VM with only a serial console access - however I didn't try this myself.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it(not the vpc part because it's not possible but to see the external IP directly on vm). steps are below:

1. Launch a VM in VPC first, while launching, in networking section, set the IP-Forwarding on. --> do it while creating, once the vm is created, you can't do that.
2. Reserve a External IP in your project and vpc.
3. In the VPC routing, create a route and for destination network x.x.x.x/32 (reserved Public IP) --> point the next hop as the VM.
4. In VM, create a Sub interface and assign the public IP directly using ip addr.

Note: This works only if you're able to reach to VPC, example: VPN to access the VM over public IP.